# vue electron builder blank page

Tags: vue.js, electron

**How I came to the problem:**

I setup an project like this:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/07/desktop-apps-electron-vue-javascript/
until it came up to the coding part, there I added custom stuff. Created Components and so on. Everything works fine in serve then I want to build it.

**What I expect as outcome:**

App working as in serve mode

**What I got:**

blank page

**What I've tried to fix the problem:**

change a wide range of path urls like:

```
 win.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
})) // with different links passing different index.html files (raw vue build, electron build and public)
```

```
win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
```

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/../public/index.html`) // aswell as the variation without file protocoll
```

Problem is I dont get errors. If I open developer console at the end of the building process by the menu bar it says, that I have to reload the page that the console is attached to the program, when I press reload, nothing happens.

Any suggestions to go further?

edit: here are my dependecies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^9.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "electron-icon-builder": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: How does your main.js look like?

Comment: kind of blank:
 ```import { createApp,  } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const vue = createApp(App);
vue.mount('#app')

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after many hours of struggling because I couldnt open a working console I found a tool called Debugtron. After a bit of optimization it throwed the error:" createProtocol is undefined ".

The autogenerated background.js missed the line:

```js
import createProtocol from "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib/createProtocol";
```